# Dividing output of one query by another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to build a tool which tells me the ratio of hours that people of different skillset will be available, as well as which workers are available, for how long and on which days.

This is what I've written so far:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d7ha.png)

In C2, there is a drop down which allows me to select different locations. The table, then is a pivot and the row at the bottom is a total of this. E.g. ColD is 26+28. I would like to add an additional row which calculates the ratio of 1 worker type to another.

I've tried simply dividing the output of one query by another, as below. On their own, these show a row of values. However, when divided by one another, I just get the value of 0.407, which is the result of dividing the first two columns by one another.

=QUERY(QUERY(Sheet1!$A$1:$M,"select SUM(J)*4 where A like '"&C2&"' and B like '1' pivot D",0), "select * offset 1",0)

/

QUERY(QUERY(Sheet1!$A$1:$M,"select SUM(J)*4 where A like '"&C2&"' pivot D",0), "select * offset 1",0)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that there might be an easier way of achieving what you want, however it's difficult to know as we can't see the source table for your queries. Having said that, if both your queries resolve to arrays with compatible dimensions (as you've suggested is the case), then wrapping everything in ARRAYFORMULA should give you multiple results which might be what you are looking for, i.e.:

```
=arrayformula(1st query / 2nd query)
```